# how to read/write the /etc/network/interfaces file

Tags: linux, networking, interface, permissions

I need to allow my local webserver (localhost) to read and write the /etc/network/interfaces file on a linux system (ubuntu).

The data manipulation of the file is done, I just need to know the best way of granting www-data the permission to do it.

I guess I could first log in as root and set permission for all to edit the file (not a big security risk since it is a mediaplayer and won't be accessed by any other user).

I could also do some nifty grouping of the user, I guess... not so seasoned with these linux things.

Anyone have a good suggestion, or input on why my suggested method is bad?

Comment: It sounds like a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: you can't access the MP from the web. It only accesses my server to download new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why would you want to do this, but generally groups are handy for this:

1. You create a new group, for example `networking`
2. then you change the group of the file to this new group (and check that it has g+rw permission)
3. finally you add `www-data` user to the `networking` group.
4. (And possibly relog, since permissions are often cached; this may not be needed for `www-data`)

Comment: The reason I want to do it is I want to be able to set wifi and other network settings in a webapp and then the digital sign /media player can fetch new settings over an api automatically. So just plug it in with a network cable and it can load new wifi configuration on its own. If you know a better or more secure way of doing it than what I am proposing I am all ears ☺